# Set redirect as permanent status (301) with MapControllerRoute .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-pages

I'm having trouble trying to set my redirect as 301 (permanent redirect). Currently, it's showing as 307 (temp status). Code below:

```
routes.MapControllerRoute("Redirect", 
       "redirect/{*path=/Test}", new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" });
```

This is using .Net Core Version 3.0.1. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC controller, you can use the [ControllerBase.RedirectToRoutePermanent Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroutepermanent?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to redirect the request. By using this method, the redirect status is 301.

Refer to the following code:

Home Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View(); 
    }
    public IActionResult Privacy2()
    {
        //return RedirectPermanent("~/Home/Privacy");

        //return RedirectToActionPermanent("Privacy", "Home");
        //You can also use the above methods,
        return RedirectToRoutePermanent("Redirect");
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Redirect",
        "redirect/{*path=/Test}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Privacy" });  
});
```

When access the Home controller Privacy2 action method, the request url: `https://localhost:44394/Home/Privacy2`, use F12 developer tools to check the Network, the output as below:

[image]